# simple linear regression failed to converge in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am new to machine learning and Tensorflow. Currently I am trying to follow the tutorial's logic to create a simple linear regression model of form  y = a*x  (there is no bias term here) . However, for some reason, the model fail to converge to the correct value "a". The data set is created by me in excel. As shown below:

[image]

here is my code that tries to run tensorflow on this dummy data set I generated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

w = tf.Variable([[5]],dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-5],dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,1),dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w),b)

label = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y,label))

data = pd.read_csv("D:\\dat2.csv")
xs = data.iloc[:,:1].as_matrix()
ys = data.iloc[:,1].as_matrix()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.000001).minimize(loss)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(optimizer,{x:xs,label:ys})
    if i%100 == 0:  print(i,sess.run(w))
print(sess.run(w))
```

below is the print out in ipython console, as you can see after 10000th iteration, the value for w is around 4.53 instead of the correct value 6. 
I would really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on what is going on wrong here. I have played around with different learning rate from 0.01 to 0.0000001, none of the setting is able to have the w converge to 6. I have read some suggesting to normalize the feature to standard normal distribution, I would like to know if this normalization is a must? without normalization, gradientdescent is not able to find the solution? Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: What if the `randbetween` was passed 0 and 0.1 instead of -2, 2?

Comment: Your learning rate is way too small. How many different values do you have ? (how many lines in your excel ?). If that number is too small that may be a problem...
You should be able to converge without any normalization if you have enough data (and with a big enough range)

Comment: @gdelab the data set contains about 160 data points. I have played with much larger learning rates like 0.1 or even 1, but to no avail. I thought by iterating 10000 times, the model should still be able to converge

Comment: After a bit more testing, the problem is in the loss function (it does not give the value it should even on a smaller dataset), I still don't know where exactly. The optimization then does minimize the loss, by diminishing w and augmenting b. Maybe a shaping problem with y or label that leads to broadcasting or sthg like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a shaping problem: y and label don't have the same shape (`[batch_size, 1]` vs `[batch_size]`). In `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, label))`, it causes tensorflow to interpret things differently from what you want, probably by using some broadcasting... Anyway, the result is that your loss is not at all the one you want.

To correct that, simply replace

```
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b)
```

by

```
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b)
y = tf.reshape(y, shape=[-1])
```

My full working code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

w = tf.Variable([[4]], dtype=tf.float64)
b = tf.Variable([10.0], dtype=tf.float64, trainable=True)
x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float64)
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w), b)
y = tf.reshape(y, shape=[-1])
label = tf.placeholder(shape=(None), dtype=tf.float64)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, label))

my_path = "/media/sf_ShareVM/data2.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(my_path, sep=";")
max_n_samples_to_use = 50
xs = data.iloc[:max_n_samples_to_use, :1].as_matrix()
ys = data.iloc[:max_n_samples_to_use, 1].as_matrix()
lr = 0.000001
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(100000):
    _, loss_value, w_value, b_value, y_val, lab_val = sess.run([optimizer, loss, w, b, y, label], {x: xs, label: ys})
    if i % 100 == 0:  print(i, loss_value, w_value, b_value)
    if (i%2000 == 0 and 0< i < 10000):  # We use a smaller LR at first to avoid exploding gradient. It would be MUCH cleaner to use gradient clipping (by global norm)
        lr*=2
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss)

print(sess.run(w))
```

Comment: You'll see that, after the first few very good steps, it converges very slowly (especially the bias). To fix it, we would need a bigger learning rate. Unfortunately we are at the boundaries of exploding gradient here, especially if you keep all values from your data, which is why we need a small learning rate. Ideally you should clip the gradient and use a bigger learning rate.

Comment: thanks @gdelab, it is indeed the shaping issue. once fixed, the model converges to right value very quickly. Thanks